# Completed 401 Unauthorized Error for omniauth devise in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I am trying to add login through gmail feature to my application.
I used 'omniauth' and 'omniauth-google-oauth2' gems,Here is my code

**User.rb**

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:omniauthable

def self.find_for_google_oauth2(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
  data = access_token.info
  user = User.where(:provider => access_token.provider, :uid => access_token.uid ).first
  if user
   return user
  else
   registered_user = User.where(:email => access_token.info.email).first
   if registered_user
     return registered_user
   else
     user = User.create(name: data["name"],
      provider:access_token.provider,
      email: data["email"],
      uid: access_token.uid ,
      password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
    )
  end
 end
end
```

**devise.rb**

```
require 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET", { access_type: "offline", approval_prompt: "" }
```

replaced APP_ID with my client_id and APP_SECRET with my client_secret

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { : omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" }
```

**omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController   

def google_oauth2    
@user = User.find_for_google_oauth2(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

if @user.persisted?
  flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
else
  session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
end
```

**authorised redirect URI**

http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback

When I try to login it gives

```
Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=fb1921cc2fd051c677bb0058e21e17fbaa028fce2e7eb669&code=4/g2xXVC2arLfYzWGqnswcIuwkDarfdW1ZzPSJRIcdUqw" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-27 16:11:31 +0530
I, [2015-10-27T16:11:31.311428 #8223]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#google_oauth2 as HTML
Parameters: {"state"=>"fb1921cc2fd051c677bb0058e21e17fbaa028fce2e7eb669", "code"=>"4/g2xXVC2arLfYzWGqnswcIuwkDarfdW1ZzPSJRIcdUqw"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
```

Is there anything wrong in my code,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Omniauth Call Back Controller , try the below code:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController   

def google_oauth2    
@user = User.find_for_google_oauth2(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

if @user.persisted?
  flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication, bypass => true
else
  session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
end
```

I just added bypass => true

Comment: Did you find the answer?